# Why isn't the Visual C++ auto-vectorizer vectorizing this simple loop?

Tags: c++, c, loops, visual-c++, vectorization

I can't figure out why Visual C++ can't auto-vectorize this loop... any ideas?

I get:

```
testvec.cpp:12: info C5002: loop not vectorized due to reason '1200'
```

where reason code 1200 is:

> Loop contains loop-carried data dependences that prevent vectorization. Different iterations of the loop interfere with each other such that vectorizing the loop would produce wrong answers, and the auto-vectorizer cannot prove to itself that there are no such data dependences.

But why?

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int const n = argc;
    double
        *const p1 = (double *)malloc(n * n * sizeof(*p1)),
        *const p2 = (double *)malloc(n * n * sizeof(*p2));
    for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
    {
        double const sj = p1[n * j];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            double const sum = p1[i] + sj, old = p1[i + n * j];
            p2[i + n * j] = sum < old ? sum : old;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not having that problem.

Comment: @FiddlingBits: Hmm what Visual C++ are you using? I'm on 32-bit, VC++ 2013.

Comment: Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Professional, 64-bit

Comment: @FiddlingBits: That doesn't even include an auto-vectorizer to begin with.

Comment: I guess that explains that. Sorry.

Comment: @FiddlingBits: No worries :)

Comment: My guess is that is that the compiler isn't smart enough to vectorize conditionals and it's just giving the wrong failure reason.

Comment: @Mysticial: I think I figured out how to fix it, but not why it's happening... see my answer below.

Comment: Does moving the newly initialized variables out of the loops help?

Comment: @Jongware: No I don't think so, but see my answer below (just posted it right now).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found how to fix it... seems like the multiplication in `n * j` is the culprit.
Hoisting it outside as `int nj = n * j;` and using `nj` in the inner loop instead fixes the problem.

I still don't know **why** this happens though.

If anyone knows, please post it!

Comment: Maybe the compiler did not like the allocation/deallocation -- after all, this might fail somewhere. You could try this (I think) by replacing it with a `malloc/free` or `new/delete` construction (whatever, since you tagged both C and C++).

Comment: @Jongware: I'm confused, which allocation or deallocation are you talking about that might fail? What does it have to do with the multiplication?

Comment: `double const sj = p1[n * j];` -- implicit allocation on the stack. It gets freed at the end of the scope. Testing with *explicit* allocation might confirm the vectorizer does not like this.

Comment: @Jongware: Wait but `sj` is allocated *outside* the loop -- why would it affect what happens *inside* the loop? And what exactly are you saying I should replace it with?

Comment: Arg -- apologies, I see I interpreted `sj` as an array...  Sorry for the confusion.